# "java.exe" salió con el código 1 - C# Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

```
"java.exe" salió con el código 1.
```

Ya intente con establecer el tamaño del montón de Java en 1G. No funciono. SDK tools esta actualizado y ya recompile varias veces.

Salida:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.D8.targets(79,5): error MSB6006: "java.exe" salió con el código 1.
```

Comment: No me acuerdo exactamente el error de codigo 1, pero me ha sucedido. El ultimo que me salio fue porque querer ejecutar un proyecto actualizado de xamarin en visual studio 2017, ese mismo proyecto no da error en visual studio 2019

Comment: Y muchas veces, es limpiar, cerrar el visual y recompilar

Comment: Ya lo intente varias veces y no funciona.

Comment: pero hiciste algo o es un proyecto nuevo?

Comment: No es nuevo pero estaba bien. Lo cerré ayer luego de probarlo sin problemas y lo abrí hoy y ahora no me deja pasar eso.
La salida dice: 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.D8.targets(79,5): error MSB6006: "java.exe" salió con el código 1.

Comment: fijate en los procesadores que tenes seleccionados y si en la ventana de salida te da algun error mas especifico, yo tuve que quitar el procesador armeaby-v7a y x86_64

Comment: Revise con tu sugerencia pero aun nada. Gracias de igual manera.